# Catch app not launching using powershell or python

Tags: python, powershell

I am using powershell to start multiple windows applications. Is there any way that I can detect if an app I'm trying to launch is failing using this? If not, is it possible to do this in Python?

`start shell:AppsFolder\[aumid]`

Comment: Something like this? > try { shell:AppsFolder\[aumid] } catch { Write-Host "failed to start app" }

Comment: I forgot the 'start'!  > try { start shell:AppsFolder\\[aumid] } catch { Write-Host "failed to start app" }